# When and how did "momentarily" come to mean "in a moment", rather than "for a moment"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, british-english, history

"Momentarily" used to mean "for a moment" only, and not "in a moment". Thus, newscasters could be divided into two clear groups: those who would say "we'll be back momentarily," and those who would not.

This restriction made sense to me, because having both definitions would promote ambiguity if a unique interpretation could not always be derived from the context. But in recent years it seems "momentarily" is regularly, maybe even more often, used to mean "in a moment" by newscasters of every caliber, and in fact this is even shown to be the definition when looked up in most dictionaries.

When did this word's meaning change? How did it come about?

Comment: Don't forget *presently*... English is a strange beast.

Comment: @Cerberus: *Language* is a strange beast.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: True. But English has never been properly domesticated.

Comment: I think that the usage "in a moment" is largely constrained to North America (being vague, because I don't know about Canadian usage). As an en-gb speaker, whenever I fly with an American airline and hear the pilot say, "We will take off momentarily," I'm tempted to say out loud, "I hope not!"

Comment: Not "I hope not" but "quite right". The plane approaches take off, then momentarily it is taking off, then it is in the air.

Comment: ha, so sayeth @Cerberus.

Comment: @cornbreadninja: Ipse dixi!

Comment: The word "momentarily" has a very explicit meaning in electrical engineering. It is the correct meaning, of course. - "fleeting".

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question. Since it's obvious that the meaning of `momentarily` is ambiguous and confusing to many, wouldn't it be more advisable to use `soon` and `briefly`? They are shorter and more precise words, after all.

Answer (score 15):

> The Patrician, Lord Vetinari:
>   'I shall deal with the matter
>   momentarily,' he said. It was a good
>   word. It always made people hesitate.
>   They were never quite sure whether he
>   meant he'd deal with it now, or just
>   deal with it briefly.
>   And no-one ever dared ask.

[*Guards! Guards!*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061020648) - Sir Terry Pratchett

Comment: Sorry. Removed my +1 because though this made me smile, and Terry Pratchett should be quoted at every opportunity, it isn't actually an answer to the question.

Comment: +1 because whatever @John says, the "soon" meaning of "momentarily" predates television announcers by many, many decades. To protest otherwise is pure pedantry.

Answer (score 10):

(answer copied over from [this later question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/what-does-the-word-momentarily-really-mean/53793#53793) closed as a dup)

I think it's misleading to suggest the two different meaning are simply "the" American and British usages. I'm sure most competent speakers on both sides of the pond are perfectly well aware the word has both meanings (and has done for centuries).

It's true Brits normally *use* it to mean *lasting for a moment*, as opposed to Americans normally using it to mean *about to happen in a moment*. But we all transparently understand the other meaning when we encounter it - and context usually makes it abundantly clear which is intended. Only pedantic Americans would fret over *"The display flickered momentarily"*, and I disown any of my fellow Brits who would take issue with *"The dam will burst momentarily"*.

The good folk over at [Merriam-Webster](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA641&dq=%22momentarily%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AeYFT9_MNora8APe-6DGAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22momentarily%22&f=false) love taking side-swipes at such pedantry. They devote nearly a whole page to this one word in that link, and it seems to me every other paragraph takes a pop at anyone claiming it (or indeed any other word) can only have one meaning.

---

To summarise the MW position, a couple of centuries ago, *momentarily* had **four** meanings - *instantly, from moment to moment, briefly,* and *very soon*. The first two have long fallen into disuse. In the early 1900s that fourth meaning, which had hitherto been quite rare, gained traction in America by extension/conflation with the *second* meaning. Both the last two meanings are currently valid in the US *and* UK, but the fourth is relatively rare in current British usage.

Comment: I'm American and deeply bothered every time I hear someone say they'll momentarily do something, especially on an airplane. I definitely do NOT want to be on a plane that takes off momentarily or be in the hands of a pilot who can't speak English!

Comment: @Tokunashi: Okay, I was exaggerating a bit with *But we **all** transparently understand...* But you probably wouldn't fancy a fag after dinner, either.

Answer (score 8):

I just searched [Google NGrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com) for the phrase "back momentarily"; the first appearance of the phrase seems to be around 1850, but the first appearance with the meaning **in**,  rather than **for**, a moment appears to be in the [*History of the Fifteenth Regiment, New Hampshire Volunteers, 1862-1863*](http://books.google.com/books?id=upEQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA308&dq=%22back%20momentarily%22&hl=en&ei=LCDoTdWjOpK4sQO89Iz7DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22back%20momentarily%22&f=false) (published 1899):

> While he was gone we received orders
>   from headquarters, and our Lieutenant
>   Pickering drew up the company,
>   expecting the captain back
>   momentarily.

In principle, I fully agree that this usage is incorrect... but I don't think we can blame anyone still living for it.

Comment: Per my comment on @Martin's answer, I really don't understand how anyone can use the word "incorrect" about a meaning that goes back well over a century. You guys should be on the board of the [Academie Francaise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise).

Comment: Your NGram link is an unrelated search term. When I searched for [back momentarily](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22back%20momentarily%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1851&lr=lang_en), the first three results were all earlier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - When I posted that link (over a year ago - nice resurrection!), I failed to include the search term and instead posted a bare link to NGrams; "Atlantis" vs. "El Dorado" is the default.  Nice catch.  However, if you'll actually **read** those first results, as I did over a year ago, you'll see that they are for phrases that _contain_ "back momentarily", but in the original sense of "briefly" rather than "immediately"... in other words, they don't answer the OP's question.  But again, nice catch.

Comment: I've just realised that the three results in my link are actually duplicates of a single instance anyway (but dated 1825, 1826, and 1834). Given you've found an instance only a few decades later (1863) where the meaning is clearly ***in** a moment* rather than ***for** a moment*, I'd say there's little to suggest any particular one of the four meanings listed by MW was the "original", or in any sense more "correct" than any other.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for "momentarily expecting" yields some very old uses with the meaning "in a moment".

From *The Fast of St. Magdelen,* by Anna Maria Porter, 1818, via [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Jyk1AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA257&dq=momentarily&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QCkGT7iGMoHPgAeln6GNAg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=momentarily&f=false).

> Momentarily expecting the appearance of this person, and winding up her spirit to sustain the rude encounter of probable insult or menace from him, she sat down on her bed, alternately listening to hear whether her enraged gaolers were coming, or ejaculating an agonized appeal to heaven.

And [from 1744](http://books.google.com/books?id=8EsDAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA562&dq=%22momentarily+expected+to+be%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oysGT4z6JoXEgAeApNSVAg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22momentarily%20expected%20to%20be%22&f=false)

> ... on the 4th we had 10 feet water in our hold, which made our condition very bad, and the dread of death appeared in every face, for we momentarily expected to be swallowed up;

There are lots of instances of "momentarily expect(s/ed/ing)" from the early 1800s with this meaning, so it's been used this way fairly regularly for at least 200 years. In fact, from the [following Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=momentarily+expecting%2Cmomentarily+expected%2C+momently+expected%2C+momently+expecting&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the phrase "momentarily expected" has been declining in use, which is very weak evidence for the word "momentarily" shifting in meaning **away** from the meaning "in a moment".

[image]

If you look at old dictionaries and grammars with Google books, you discover that some of them (for example, [Chambers's,](http://books.google.com/books?id=TaECAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA327&dq=momentarily+momently+%22in+a+moment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eAIHT9OBD8f2ggfG06z2DA&ved=0CGUQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=momentarily%20momently%20%22in%20a%20moment%22&f=false) 1867) say that the word you were **supposed to** use for this sense of *momentarily* was *momently,* but from the above Ngram, it appears that *momentarily* has always been more popular than *momently,* even for this meaning.

If you look at Ngrams, you discover that *momently* was also used for both meanings in the early 1800s:

> And from this chasm, with ceaseless turmoil seething,
>   As if this earth in fast thick pants were breathing,
>   A mighty fountain momently was forced; —*Kubla Khan,* Coleridge, 1797.

What I think may have happened was that in the early 1800s, there were two words, *momentarily* and *momently,* with essentially the same two meanings (either "in a moment" and "for a moment"). Some prescriptive dictionary writers decided to assign one meaning to *momentarily* and the other to *momently,* but it never caught on. To defend the dictionary writers, this difference in meaning is indeed justified etymologically, since *momentarily* is derived from *momentary,* meaning *for a moment,* while *momently* is derived directly from *moment.*

The word *momently* is now effectively gone from the English language, but prescriptive grammarians still say that *momentarily* should only have the one meaning.

Comment: As pointed out by MW in my link, Webster himself specifically chose *momently* **expect** as an example because it can embody two of the original four meanings *(in a moment, every moment)*. And *momently/momentarily* are (were?) really just alternative inflections for the same word, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Momentarily does not mean soon.  If it did, why not ditch "soon"?  It means for a short while, e.g. "he stayed looking at the house momentarily, before moving on."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and your answer does not appear to [answer the original question](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Besides, the dictionaries seem to disagree with you, certainly in North America.

Answer (score -3):

The meaning never changed. The word is widely misused in North America. It still means "for a moment", not "in a moment".

Comment: How many times, and for how many years, does a word need to be used with a specific meaning before you accept that *it really does have* that meaning? Even if you are *very* old, "momentarily" has been commonly used to mean "in a short time" for longer than you've been alive.